# jQuery UI datepicker css

Tags: css, jquery-ui, themes

How can I apply my own theme to a datepicker
or at least apply a theme from jQuery to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend using http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/,  if that doesn't help you look more indepth into the ui.datepicker.css file and the ui.theme.css files.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you are using the jQuery UI datepicker.  If so, you can design a custom theme at the jQuery [UI ThemeRoller](http://ui.jquery.com/themeroller/), then modify the resulting CSS file to you tweak it to your liking.  You'll get CSS and custom images for the hover effects.  The javascript will generate code that references the classes in the CSS file.