# Jquery DatePicker Some Display Changes

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the jquery datepicker. I have to change some display showing the calendar.

I don't have enough reputation to post an image so [i have posted in jquery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-change-jquery-datepicker-display-changes). Kindly look over it and guide me and how to implement this.

Comment: In your example you show last few days of previous month, but first few PLUS a week in the next month, is that the intent here?

Comment: Ya i think your correct it should be intented....for eg it should like the ajax calendar extendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you simply want to show the current month plus any days in incomplete weeks - days from other months, you can do this as such:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true
    });
});
```

If you wish to show the next months incomplete week, PLUS one more week, you will need to do this differently.

The `selectOtherMonths: true` portion above sets if the OTHER months dates are selectable (true) or not (false), the current months days are more bold visually but ALL are selectable if this is true.

EDIT: The question remains then, if you want the EXTRA week of dates listed from the NEXT month?  IF that last is true, I think perhaps we are looking at the need for custom code or another plug-in to use.

Comment: i use this code means [28][29][30][31] and [1] in the bottom comes disable mode for the September  month and if i click the next month October it shows same Su------Fr [25][26][27][28][29][30] is coming where [27] is highlighted and in bottom [1][2][3][4][5].

Comment: I am having trouble with your explaination and IF you need the EXTRA week and not simple FILL-IN of all weeks.

Comment: Thanks it help lot.is there any possible to change that other months css alone

Comment: See this question for CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520811/jquery-ui-datepicker-css

Comment: Mark, I am interested in how to display an additional week

Comment: @Angus - please post a new question to SO as that is a new and different question.

Answer (score 0):

Use following option to show other months

`$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true
});`

To change the styling override the following css class

`.ui-priority-secondary`